# Invoking an activity from Android Library(.jar)?

Tags: android, android-intent, jar, android-activity

I have created an Android Library Project which contains several Activities. I want to reuse these activities in other projects. How can I do this? I have added the project vi:

> project->Android->Add(Android Library Project.)

Then added the required details to Android Manifest file.

Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="org.testlib.com"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-libraryandroid:name="org.mainlib.com" android:required="true"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name=".TestLibActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.mainlib.com.MainActivity"/>                 
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Code to start activity:

```
Intent myintent=new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);
```

How can I invoke an activity from my jar file?

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand your question. Do you mean

> How to start 'TestLibActivity' from outside the Library

?

If that's the case, you can call it by calling `Intent myintent=new Intent(v.getContext(),org.testlib.com.TestLibActivity.class);
   startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);`

Of course you have to add the right import in your activity and add the library to your project.

Comment: No I have a Android Library project package ie;org.mainlib.com.MainActivity.class .I want invoke that class in another project.So I am import the .jar file of Android Library project (org.mainlib.com) to the current project.But I didnt get the MainActivity to the current project.Another one problem is:If we create the UI programmatically it willl works fine.

Comment: when we use the jar file the resources xml file didnt load to the new project.

Comment: `import org.mainlib.com.MainActivity; inside button clik:Intent(v.getContext(),org.mainlib.com.MainActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(myintent, 0);` But Its not working.

Answer (score 2):

If you've created an android library and added it correctly (seems like it). Then the only thing you do is the same thing you'd do with a regular activity. The only difference being you import a path from your library project instead of your own project.

On a side note you don't need to add the library in your manifest. You only need add the library project through the project properties.

Comment: when I am delete the library from manifest file the follwing error will occur..ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {org.testlib.com/org.mainlib.com.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes but you should declare the activity in the manifest of your libraryproject not your main project.